# ASP.net redirect problem

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

This gives a 404 not found:

```
<rewrite url="~/forum/viewforum.php?f=([0-9]+)" to="~/Handlers/PermRedirect.ashx?ID=$1&amp;action=forumcat" processing="stop"/>
```

But this works:

```
<rewrite url="~/forum/viewforum.php" to="~/Handlers/PermRedirect.ashx?ID=5&amp;action=forumcat" processing="stop"/>
```

Am I handling this wrong?  I'm just trying to pass the querystring data from the original url to the redirect script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems that you forgot the "\" escape character for "?". Give a try this.

```
<rewrite url="~/forum/viewforum.php\?f=([0-9]+)" to="~/Handlers/PermRedirect.ashx?ID=$1&amp;action=forumcat" processing="stop"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something here will help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx